# What resources are required to run Flash on Android?

Tags: android

I have HTC T-Mobile device having Android OS 1.6, Eclair platform. I doubt if Flash Adobe Air can run on that. Because that is the only supported on 2.1 and 2.2. Please confirm.

Also can i upgrade my device's OS to Froyo by downloading the OS from android.source.com?
I have downloaded SDK 2.1 and 2.2 on my machine. Can i develop and run flash games on the AVD/emulator?

Please comment and reply precisely to the aforementioned questions. Thank you

Comment: Only Froyo (2.2) supports flash at the moment, and 1.6 is not Eclair - that's 2.1.

You should be able to run flash via the AVD/emulator, but you need to install Flash Player 10.1 beta first.

Comment: The Flash Player is only available on the Android Market. That, plus lack of emulated graphics acceleration, means the Flash Player will not run on an emulator.

Comment: You meant to say on any emulator i.e. even on 2.2?Thanks

Comment: Awesome. People answering in the comments and question posers adding random answers with links to tutorials?

Comment: This is because i have not come up with a practical and concrete solution so far.There is too much talk about flash arriving on android but there is no mention of flash on the official Froyo/Android 2.2 page. This is just too confusing!

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of Flash from Adobe won't work on anything prior to 2.2. That is more to do with Adobe targeting that version rather than flash being something that Android 1.5/1.6 intrinsically cannot do.

There have been flash players on Android before, I understand that HTC used to bundle flash capability with the HTC Hero.

You can certainly download 2.2 from source and build it for your device but you must have two things prior to doing that:

1. root access to your device
2. proprietary drivers for your device that will work with that android build

If you have a G1, then you are in luck because the [cyanogen mod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) can be installed on a G1 plus they will be porting 2.2 to it (along with the Nexus One and a few others)

Comment: Thanks Niel! We do have G1. So we can upgrade it's OS from 1.6 to Froyo? If yes then what's the procedure?

Comment: Where is the procedure the OS from 1.6 to 2.2 or Froyo on the website that you've given here exactly? Waiting for your reply.

Comment: The link is to cyanogenMOD which is built with 2.1 (and currently release a test build of 2.2)

The wiki at the site tells you how to install it and it's the best guide around. Just follow the instructions for the G1 and you should be good. Read it through a few times before though.